# Collision between player and heightmap

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, collision-detection, lwjgl

Im programming a small project, an opengl height map.
It is build of triangles, which points are fit to the right y position (read out of an image).

The player is represanted by a cuboid. (p1, p2, ... p8).
now, i want to implement collision detection between the player and the heightmap.

I thought about split the whole world in cubes, and this cubes again in cubes, and then 
distribute the triangles of the heightmap in this cubes (then check for the big cube, the smaller cube, which contains the player, and then check all triangles for collision).

But which collision detection method would be the best here, and how could i implement it?
(By the way, im using lwjgl [java])

Comment: whats so bad about saying thank you? -.-

Comment: please read this : http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: wheres the point? One reason, why my question doenst fit the conditinos?

Comment: Your question is IMHO just too broad. And now for something completely different: Why not map the player position to the image and check if it is above ground?

Comment: hm, i think i dont understood you. What do you mean by "map it to the image" ?

Comment: You are said you generate the heighmap from an image. If you find out where the player is on the image you could use this to get the terrain height.

Comment: yes that would be a possibility, but the problem would be the interpolating... the player can move between the triangles too, so this would only work for a blocky world or something like this ^^

Comment: In that case you will really have to build a scene graph like you suggested and the check if the player collides with any of them. And that's where the "too broad" from earlier comes back into play (-_-)

Comment: "check if the player collides with any of them"

yes, and HOW to do THIS, was the actual question xD